# CoreData: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key folderPosition

Tags: swift, core-data, key-value-coding

**UPDATED - CODE WITH SOLUTION BELOW**

I have used CoreData on a number of different projects without issue but this one has me stumped. The only difference between this and previous projects is I am using CloudKit.

All I am trying to do is set a value for a current record. I have an entity called Folders and in that entity is an attribute named folderPosition which is an Int16.

My code to update the value looks like this:

```
static func updateFolderPositionsAfterFolderDeletion(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = AppDelegate.viewContext) {
    
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Folders")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "folderPosition", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    do {
        if let fetchResults = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Folders] {
            if fetchResults.count != 0 {
                for items in fetchResults {
                   managedObjectContext.setValue(items.folderPosition - 1, forKey: "folderPosition")
                }
            }
        }
        try? managedObjectContext.save()
    }
    catch {
        print("Catch")
    }
}
```

However I keep getting the following error:

> quotelibc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSManagedObjectContext 0x600001cb4c30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key folderPosition.'
> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSExceptionquote>

The other strange thing is, I have an attribute called folderName (String), if I update with the same code I get no crashes and I can see that it iterates through all the folders available in CoreData and updates the value for folderName but then when I fetch the data back, the folder names have not changed. It's all very odd.

**Updated Code Based on Helpful Comments and Answers - Thank You!**

```
static func updateFolderPositionsAfterFolderDeletion(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = AppDelegate.viewContext) {
    
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Folders")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "folderPosition", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    do {
        if let fetchResults = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Folders] {
            for (index, folder) in fetchResults.enumerated() {
                folder.folderPosition = (Int16(index))
            }
        }
        try? managedObjectContext.save()
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using key-value coding instead of accessing the properties directly? And for this case the issue is pretty obvious, NSManagedObjectContext doesn't have a property `folderPosition`, maybe try to set it on your model object instead? ;) This even more emphasise the advantage of accessing properties directly so the compiler directly can tell you if you have an error.

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson - that makes sense. I basically think I couldn't see the wood for the trees and ended up going on some massively convoluted bug search! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all and unrelated to the issue the logic to reindex the position looks pretty weird. Actually you have to decrement the index only from the item at position *deleted position + 1*.

As mentioned in the comments the error is caused by a typo. You mean

```
items.setValue(items.folderPosition - 1, forKey: "folderPosition")
```

instead of

```
managedObjectContext.setValue(items.folderPosition - 1, forKey: "folderPosition")
```

There are many bad practices in the code.

- The naming is confusing. Name entities and loop elements in singular form: `Folder` and `for item in ...`.
- Avoid redundant information. Rename `folderPosition` to `position`
- Prefer dot notation over KVC.
- Take advantage of the generic fetch request: `NSFetchRequest<Folders>`.
- Never check for an empty string or empty array with `count == 0`. There is `isEmpty`.
- The empty check is redundant anyway. The loop is being skipped if the array is empty.
- Never print meaningless literal strings in `catch` blocks. Print the `error`.

---

```
static func updateFolderPositionsAfterFolderDeletion(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = AppDelegate.viewContext) {
    
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Folders>(entityName: "Folders")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "folderPosition", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    do {
        let folders = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for folder in folders {
           folder.folderPosition = folder.folderPosition - 1
        }
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

To reindex the entire data set starting at 0 there is a smarter way:

```
for (index, folder) in folders.enumerated() {
    folder.folderPosition = index
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vadian - to be honest I think I'm losing the plot! I completely forgot I was working with a NSManagedObject Class...probably too long in the rabbit hole and staring at my machine.
In terms of the other tips, thanks they make sense and I do need to work harder at trying to improve my code.